# Automated Recurring Billing (ARB) process using php

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-arb

I have implemented ARB successfully. But i need to test it, if it actually working

I have added schedule as

```
  paymentSchedule: {
            interval: {
                length: 7,
                unit: "days"
            },
            startDate: "2016-09-22",
            totalOccurrences: 9999
        },
```

As per their api documentation, i need to setup minimum of 7 days.

Can't i test re-occurring happens within 1-2 hours?

Thanks

Comment: No, there is no such thing as hourly billing.